# Changing ToolBar Item Size

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to change the size of the image in the toolbar of a my navigationController.

my idea was to create an `IBOutlet` for the item and change it programmatically, since it is not possible to do this in IB.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var chatsBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

Now I tried to access the imageView, but I think the imageView is part of the `UIButton` how can i get access to it?

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can access/set the image of your `UIBarButtonItem` with `chatsBarButton.image` not `imageView`

Comment: I'm trying to access the imageView Frame